# Convert an Object instance to the real subclass instance dynamically

Tags: java, reflection

Background:

I have hundreds of XXXFaultMsg classes generated from a WSDL file, they all have a method `getFaultMsg()` but they are extended from `Exception` directly. I have a function with argument Exception e, where e might be instance of one of the XXXFaultMsg classes.

Challenge:

I want to invoke `getFaultMsg()` on e if it is an instance of XXXFaultMsg.

I have written `if (e.getClass().getName().endsWith("FaultMsg"))` to detect whether e is an instance of XXXFaultMsg. Then how can I declare a var with type XXXFaultMsg and cast e to it and call `getFaultMsg()` on it?

P.S. I don't want to construct a long list of `if (e instanceof XXXFaultMsg)` cause there are over 100 XXXFaultMsg classes.

Comment: *but they are extended from Exception directly* time to refactor maybe

Comment: The solution here is to fix the generation.

Comment: If you're not able to restructure the classes, you would have to use reflection to call the method.

Comment: They are WebService client stubs generated from WSDL by JAX-WS and the WSDL file is provided other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have one method which takes no args:

```
Method methodToFind = null;
if (e.getClass().getName().endsWith("FaultMsg")){
    try {
      methodToFind = e.getClass().getMethod("getFaultMsg", (Class<?>[]) null);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
      // Your exception handling goes here
    }
}
```

Invoke it if present:

```
if(methodToFind == null) {
   // Method not found.
} else {
   // Method found. You can invoke the method like
   methodToFind.invoke(e, (Object[]) null);
}
```